# Bind value to selected items

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, data-binding, listboxitem

I need to use data from main menu in another method that involved sub menu and main menu. But selected item can only bind two value. I tried another way but it seems the value cannot be retrieved or idk how to retrieved it. Please help me.

```
Public Sub BindDataToListBox(ByVal menuData As DataTable, ByVal dikunciListBox As ListBox,
                          ByVal dibukaListBox As ListBox, ByVal dikunci1ListBox As ListBox, ByVal dibuka1ListBox As ListBox)

    Dim lastMainMenu As String = ""

    For Each row As DataRow In menuData.Rows
        Dim objectId As String = row("OBJECTID").ToString()
        Dim objectDesc As String = row("OBJECTDESC").ToString()
        Dim objectType As String = row("OBJECTTYPE").ToString()
        Dim iAllowValue As String = row("IALLOW").ToString()

        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(iAllowValue) OrElse iAllowValue = "0" Then
            dikunciListBox.Items.Add(New ListItem(objectDesc, objectId))
        ElseIf iAllowValue = "1" Then
            Dim dibukaItem As New ListItem(objectDesc, objectId)

            dibukaItem.Attributes("MainMenuObjectId") = objectId
            dibukaItem.Attributes("MainMenuObjectDesc") = objectDesc

            dibukaListBox.Items.Add(dibukaItem)

            Dim submenus As DataTable = Nothing
            submenus = objClass.GetSubMenuDataPR(ddlIdStaff.SelectedItem.Value, objectId)

            If submenus IsNot Nothing AndAlso submenus.Rows.Count > 0 Then

                Dim hasIAAllowZero As String = If(submenus.AsEnumerable().Any(Function(subRow) Not IsDBNull(subRow("IALLOW")) AndAlso Convert.ToDecimal(subRow("IALLOW")) = 0), "True", "False")
                Dim hasIAAllowOne As String = If(submenus.AsEnumerable().Any(Function(subRow) Not IsDBNull(subRow("IALLOW")) AndAlso Convert.ToDecimal(subRow("IALLOW")) = 1), "True", "False")

                If hasIAAllowZero = "True" OrElse hasIAAllowZero Is Nothing Then
                    DisplayMenuLabelClose(objectDesc, objectId)
                End If

                If hasIAAllowOne = "True" Then
                    DisplayMenuLabel(objectDesc, objectId)
                End If

                For Each subRow As DataRow In submenus.Rows
                    Dim subObjectId As String = subRow("OBJECTID").ToString()
                    Dim subObjectDesc As String = subRow("OBJECTDESC").ToString()
                    Dim subIAAllowValue As String = subRow("IALLOW").ToString()

                    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(subIAAllowValue) OrElse subIAAllowValue = "0" Then
                        Dim dikunci1Item As New ListItem(subObjectDesc, subObjectId)

                        dikunci1Item.Attributes("MainMenuObjectId") = objectId
                        dikunci1Item.Attributes("MainMenuObjectDesc") = objectDesc

                        dikunci1ListBox.Items.Add(dikunci1Item)
                    ElseIf subIAAllowValue = "1" Then
                        Dim dibuka1Item As New ListItem(subObjectDesc, subObjectId)

                        dibuka1Item.Attributes("MainMenuObjectId") = objectId
                        dibuka1Item.Attributes("MainMenuObjectDesc") = objectDesc

                        dibuka1ListBox.Items.Add(dibuka1Item)
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message? What exactly is not binding properly? What is happening that shouldn't be or should be happening but isn't?

Comment: This seems like you need to start placing some break points and running your debugger to figure out where the logic failure is. Also, you've passing a bunch of params into that function and they are all byVal. If you're trying to modify the actual listbox you passed in, you'll need to pass them by reference or `ByRef`

Comment: @ClearlyClueless Not true, because the list box is a reference type, it can be modified.  `ByRef` would only be appropriate if the writer wished to point to a different list box, but it's not necessary for changes to the given list box.

Comment: Is this desktop, or webforms? In desktop land you can bind a data source with "many" columns, and the selected item can return multiple columns. In web land, then a listbox ONLY has 2 values, and the original data source row can't be used.  So, for web based, you can have a display value, and a hidden value (in most cases the PK row value). So, upon selecting an option you get the PK value, and based on that, you can pull additional columns from the database based on that PK value.

Comment: @ClearlyClueless i do debug. This part:                                                                                     Dim dibuka1Item As New ListItem(subObjectDesc, subObjectId)

                        dibuka1Item.Attributes("MainMenuObjectId") = objectId
                        dibuka1Item.Attributes("MainMenuObjectDesc") = objectDesc                        I'm trying to bind more value such as objectId and objectDesc. When i tried to use it in another method it has nothing in it. I want to store more data, so when i selected the list item in the list box. The data can be use

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal webforms sir.

Comment: @ClearlyClueless i want to bind more data to the item. I have a list box that display a list of item under it. So each item only can store two values either value/text or both. But here i tried to bind more than two. I tried to use attributes and later retrieve them in another method but when i try to use it, the value is nothing. I need to store more data. I received no error messages, my code and website can be run. But the output was not accurate.